# How to run android app in all connected devices or emulators at the same time from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to run an android app in all connected devices or emulators at the same time from Android Studio?

We are able to run an android app in all connected devices or emulators at the same time from Eclipse. But how in Android Studio?

Any Suggestions will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold down SHIFT and click each device you want to run your app on when the device chooser is displayed.

This only works for running the app, if you choose to debug, this is limited to one device only

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying to figure it out navigating through all main menu options... only to find out it's just holding SHIFT key haa! :)

Answer (score 7):

No need to install any plugin. Just click the run button in the toolbar and then select all devices in the ""device chooser" dialog

[image]

Answer (score 6):

2022 Answer:

In Android Studio's top toolbar, click the dropdown that lets you select your device/emulator. In the dropdown, click `Select Multiple Devices`. Select the devices you want.

Then click green `Run` button and all devices will load the app at same time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you run this view will appear, then you can select all available devices. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Install the BashSupport plugin and add the following as a Bash config to the last thing that has to run in the build order:

$ adb shell am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname

For example create a Run Configuration with the make build called "build" or whatever and a separate Config with a Bash running the above Terminal command. In the Bash config at the bottom add the above "build" config as a "Before Launch" > "Add another configuration". So that it first makes the project and THEN execute the bash command.