# How to perform testing of a chat/socket.io feature in an Android emulator?

Tags: android, socket.io, emulation

So I'm new to android development and I'm just wondering if it's possible to test "chat" feature (socket.io) of the app in an emulator or do I have to build two APK and install in two devices?

P.S I'm coming from web app development wherein I simply open two new window tabs to test socket.io signaling between two users :p

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Click the `Run` icon then press `SHIFT` key to select two or more devices.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410957/2098493